# django url tag with dynamic app_label

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-class-based-views

i'm trying to create a dynamic url tag for my class based listview. it's needed for a delete button on every list item it loops over. the issue is that I use this template in multiple apps and want to reuse it.
what currently works:
[filename.html]

```
{% for file in object_list %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{file.stream}} </td>
        <td>{{file.regExpFilename}}</td>
        <form class="delete-form" method="POST" action="{% url 'MyApp1:filenames_delete' pk=file.stream %}">
            <button type="submit" value="delete" class="btn-delete"
              onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete {{file.stream}} {{file.regExpFile}}?')">
              Delete
            </button>
```

core.urls.py

```
"Filename":[
            path('filenames/', views.FilenameView.as_view(), name='filenames'),
            path('filenames/create', views.FilenameCreateView.as_view(), name='filenames_create'),
            path('filenames/delete/<pk>', views.FilenameDeleteView.as_view(), name='filenames_delete'),
```

core.views.filenames.py

```
class FilenameView(generic.ListView):

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs) -> dict:
        model_name = self.model._meta.model_name
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        app_label = self.model._meta.app_label
        context["create_url"] = reverse("{}:filenames_create".format(app_label))
        return context
```

But I want to remove the 'MyApp' to make it reusable for multiple apps.

Many Thanks,

Comment: thanks for the input @Charnel. but when I try this it's missing a 'PK'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create [custom template processor](https://labofcoding.com/how-write-and-use-custom-template-processors-django/):

```
def apps_context_processor(request):
    return {
        'item_delete_url': reverse(f'{request.resolver_match.app_name}:filenames_delete')
    }
```

And then use this in your template `url` tag.